# Comments on R Markdown html output

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am not sure it is the proper place for such a question. Eventually, tell me and I will delete it.

Imagine a colleague with limited technological competences. No competences on R at all. Is there a way or a command that allows to create an R Markdown html (with the `Knitr` package) output which accepts comments in the similar way of a text editor?

[image]

The matter has no mention on the website of R markdown http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ nor on of the `Knitr` package http://yihui.name/knitr/.

Comment: I'm not sure about an html file with comments, but you can render your rmarkdown file into a MS word doc that can use comments.

Comment: One possible solution would be to interlace the comments directly onto the RMarkdown file and then color the commented text a certain color. It certainly wouldn't a side bar but it may be an interesting fix.

Comment: Try something like https://www.diigo.com/tools/diigolet (not baked into Rmarkdown but prbly suitable for your needs)

Comment: @hrbrmstr, your suggestion is really interesting. I will report the result. It appears to be suitable for inexperienced users.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure such functionality exists, but I could think about how this could be emulated

- Abusing links, and have browser configuraion which shows link on hovering,
  and maybe make such links in different color (linkcolor class?)

  ```
  [MM](another bad idea)
  ```
- Abusing **R** code, you'll get code rectangle with just a text

  ````
  ```{r, echo=TRUE, eval=FALSE}
  MM: another bad idea 
  ```
  ````
- Abusing some **R** package which generates inlined HTML, say *xtable*

  ````
  ```{r results="asis", echo=FALSE}
  comments.df <- data.frame(c("WHO", "MM"), c("CMT", "Another bad idea"))
  print(xtable(comments.df), type = "html", include.rownames = FALSE)    
  ```
  ````

Frankly, would be interested in the better answer, really good question...

Comment: The first hypothesis I think is the most interesting. Perhaps, it is the one that could meet the need of a really non-expert user. I am going to test it in a couple of days.