# Don't show HTML comment in source of rendered HTML

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

When knitting the `Rmd` below and checking the HTML source, the source will - unsurprisingly - include `Don't show me in the HTML source please because I want to be secret!`. Is there a way to just have this in the Rmd source and not have it in the source of the rendered HTML.

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

<!--# Don't show me in the HTML source please because I want to be secret! -->
````

**Disclaimer:**
I'm aware that one answer is: Don't use this functionality like that since its not in the design scope. Thus, currently my go-to method is to create a chunk with `eval=FALSE` and put the comments in there.

````
```{r, eval=FALSE}
# Don't show me in the HTML source please because I want to be secret!
```
````

Anyway I am curious if there's another way.

Kind of related to this thread in certain ways:
[Comments on R Markdown html output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539708/comments-on-r-markdown-html-output)

Comment: You want `echo = FALSE`, not `eval = FALSE`. At any rate, yes, that’s the way to do this.

Comment: Actually the implication here is that `echo = FALSE` is set as default as per setup chunk (see first code segment) but thanks anyway.